# AngularJS contenteditable blur on Enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blur

I have a directive which i add on a div in order to be able to edit it's content and make a two-way binding to the scope. I wish to blur when I press the return button, I've tried `element[0].blur();` as you can see below. However this doesn't work. What should I do?

```
.directive("contenteditable", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            function read() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
            }
            ngModel.$render = function() {
                element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
            };
            element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });


            element.css('outline','none');
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                if(event.which === 13) {
                    element[0].blur();
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're mising ng-model inside HTML:

```
<input type="text" contenteditable ng-model="myModel"/> //add ng-model.
```

Because your directive requires ng-model.

See here, it works well: http://plnkr.co/edit/g0qtbFJb1V4OxcXNRTVf?p=preview

Using a div instead of input tag: http://plnkr.co/edit/UiosU1WvyUvhgLBlzX6r?p=preview

Comment: Oh, yes it works with an input, but I'm using a contenteditable div. <div contenteditable ng-model="myModel"/>, I didn't forgot the ng-model. http://plnkr.co/edit/DOmheYADNC7Z3cO7H5Et?p=preview

Comment: Even using a div, it still works well without any trick, please see: http://plnkr.co/edit/UiosU1WvyUvhgLBlzX6r?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the trick is to call `$window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` before calling `element[0].blur();`